# Re-train a neural network discarding its memory?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gpu

```
r = s \[Function] i \[Function] ImageResize[i, s];
ab = ColorSeparate[#, "LAB"][[2 ;;]] &;
out = ImageData /@ ab[# // r@{56, 56}] &;
imgs = Import /@ FileNames["*.jpg", dir, 2]; (*dir = somewhere on my disk*)
data = Table[i -> out@i, {i, imgs}];
```

---

```
raw = NetModel[
  "Colorful Image Colorization Trained on ImageNet Competition Data",
  "UninitializedEvaluationNet"
];
nex = NetTrain[raw, data, TargetDevice -> "GPU"]
```

performs training but produces results that fail to colorize no matter what. (All experiences described are same with/without `TargetDevice -> "GPU"`.)

The `LAB` `A` and `B` channels the above produces after training are always empty.

1. Using `NetInitialize[raw]` before training does not help.
2. `NetModel["Colorful Image Colorization Trained on ImageNet Competition \
   Data", "Properties"]` has no

   1. `TrainingNetwork`
   2. `UninitializedTrainingNetwork`

---

```
raw = NetModel[
  "Colorful Image Colorization Trained on ImageNet Competition Data",
  "EvaluationNet"
];
nex = NetTrain[raw, data, TargetDevice -> "GPU"]
```

produces different results but it is not clear to me what this does.

1. Does the above continue training an already-trained `EvaluationNetwork`?
2. Is there a way to discard the memory of a neural network to have it start training from scratch?

Comment: You can get `"UninitializedEvaluationNet"` from `NetModel` for that network the same way you're currently getting `"EvaluationNet`. Further, `NetInitialize[net, All]` will reset _all_ trainable weights in the net including those already trained, while `NetInitialize[net]` will initialize only weights that have not yet been trained.

Comment: Getting `"UninitializedEvaluationNet"` produces empty zero-valued ImageData as outputs for the `LAB` `A` and `B` channels as mentioned in my question. I will try `NetInitialize[net, All]` now and let you know.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see that in your question!